# ComboBox update when clicked to dropdown list event

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to ask how to execute a mysql update command, I already have the command ready but I do not know how to put the event on the combo box arrow when clicked, my combobox note is dropdownlist style.

[ANOTHER image for help .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrebr.png)

' This code refresh combo on formload, but i need on clicked .
  someone can help ?

```
Private Sub carrega_empresas()

    Using conexao As MySqlConnection = GetConnectionMySQL()
        conexao.Open()

        Try

            Dim Query As String
            Query = "SELECT * FROM tb_empresa"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, conexao)
            Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            While READER.Read
                Dim empresa = READER.GetString("empresa")
                cboempresa.Items.Add(empresa)

            End While

            conexao.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conexao.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Using

End Sub
```

[FOR Update data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOluI.png)

[SOLVED By @LarsTech and @OL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z2NX.png)

Comment: Click on the lightning bolt in the properties box to see the list of available events.  It is not very clear what your question is about.

Comment: in this case i need execute this command : 

 Using conexao As MySqlConnection = GetConnectionMySQL()
            conexao.Open()

            Try

                Dim Query As String
                Query = "SELECT * FROM tb_empresa"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, conexao)
                Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
                READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
                While READER.Read
                    Dim empresa = READER.GetString("empresa")
                    cboempresa.Items.Add(empresa)

                End While

Comment: Command refreshs with select with itens updated.

Comment: updated for more info.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use SelectedIndexChanged event.
For that click on the lightning bolt and double click on SelectedIndexChanged.
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) about this event

Updated:
DropDown event could be the one you are looking for - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ty, for read , but i need when clicked on dropdownlist arrow to list , execute mysql command in post .

Comment: @Perroni There's no reason to fill your list as the user is clicking the drop down arrow.  It needs to be filled before that.

Comment: @Perroni Then DropDown event could be the one you are looking for. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Because i have another form active refreshing data .

Comment: I will try this @LarsTech

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown _ 
    (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _ 
    Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
    MessageBox.Show("Typical installation is strongly recommended.", _
    "Install information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub

making tests and back with results.

Comment: @LarsTech works , but he getting two times itens but i think i can solve this when getting two times. ty for help .

Comment: @Perroni You can click the checkbox near my answer to mark that it is correct

Comment: ty, OL too .
i dont have 15 points for +rep . 
sorry for this .

but i mark answer